# Can I reset baseline in Flyway without Teams Edition?

Tags: flyway

We are using `Flyway version 7.5.4` to deploy changes to schemas in a `Snowflake database`. We are using the community version and not the teams version. For one schema in a database, the repair takes hours because there have been many deployments to it.

Is there a way with the community version to `re-baseline` it so that it doesn't take so long to repair? If so, can you share how I would do that?

Comment: When you say "rebaseline", does that mean your database has already once been baselined? If that's the case then I think your only option is to delete the schema history table and to rebaseline from scratch. Bear in mind that your target database will then lose its migration history, which may or may not be important to you. I guess you could rename the table rather than drop it if you want to refer back to this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  we rebaselined it when we implemented Flyway.  Now the history table has become so large that it takes a very long time to repair.  Thank you for your answer.   That will definitely work.  I just wasn't sure if I could accomplish it with the command line with the community version.

Comment: Yes, it will work in the community version. Personally I'd like to think one day there could be a way to re-baseline without removing the schema history table, but in the meantime this is probably what I'd suggest.